# Por que o parâmetro escape não é reconhecido no HtmlHelper do Cakephp?

Tags: html, cakephp-2

Ao tentar criar uma imagem como link no cakephp usando o HtmlHelper, o código HTML é gerado como String no browser

```
<?php echo $this -> html -> link(
'Visualizar'
.$this -> html -> image('icone_visualizar.png').' |  ',
 array('escape'=>false,'controller'=>'documents','action'=>'admin_view',$document['Document']['id']));?>
```

Resultado

```
<a href="/documents/admin_view/130">Visualizar&lt;img src="/img/icone_visualizar.png" alt="" /&gt; |  </a>
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar o H do Html Maiúsculo?

Comment: mas o objeto HtmlHelper está sendo considerado , tanto que aparece o link e a imagem em html no final , porém a imagem aparece em forma de string

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que você está passando o 'escape'=>false no segundo parâmetro, que é o da $url, quando segundo a [documentação](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/pt/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/HTML.html#link) ele deve ser passado no 3º parâmetro ($options)

Tente mudar o seu código para algo do tipo

```
<?php echo $this -> html -> link(
'Visualizar'.$this -> html -> image('icone_visualizar.png').' |  ',
array('controller'=>'documents','action'=>'admin_view',$document['Document']['id']),
array('escape'=>false);?>
```